# Google script origin request url

Tags: url, google-apps-script, cors

I'm developing a Google Sheets add-on. The add-on calls an API. In the API configuration, a url like https://longString-script.googleusercontent.com had to be added to the list of urls allowed to make requests from another domain.
Today, I noticed that this url changed to https://sameLongString-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com.
The url changed about 3 months after development start.

I'm wondering what makes the url to change because it also means a change in configuration in our back-end every time.

EDIT: Thanks for both your responses so far. Helped me understand better how this works but I still don't know if/when/how/why the url is going to change.
Quick update, the changing part of the url was "-1lu" for another user today (but not for me when I was testing). It's quite annoying since we can't use wildcards in the google dev console redirect uri field. Am I supposed to paste a lot of "-xlu" uris with x from 1 to like 10 so I don't have to touch this for a while?

Comment: Alexandre Raffin,were you you able to find the root cause of changing url issue?

Answer (score 2):

For people coming across this now, we've also just encountered this issue while developing a Google Add-on. We've needed to add multiple origin urls to our oauth client for sign-in, following the `longString-#lu-script.googleusercontent.com` pattern mentioned by OP.

This is annoying as each url has to be entered separately in the authorized urls field (subdomain or wildcard matching isn't allowed). Also this is pretty fragile since it breaks if Google changes the urls they're hosting our add-on from. Furthermore I wasn't able to find any documentation from Google confirming that these are the script origins.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are managed by the host in various ways. At the most basic level, when you build a web server you decide what to call it and what to call any pages on it. Google and other large content providers with farms of servers and redundant data centers and everything are going to manage it a bit differently, but for your purposes, it will be effectively the same in that ... you need to ask them since they are the hosting provider of your cloud content.

Something that MIGHT be related is that Google rolled out some changes recently dealing with the googleusercontent.com domain and picassa images (or at least was scheduled to do so.) So the google support forums will be the way to go with this question for the freshest answers since the cause of a URL change is usually going to be specific to that moment in time and not something that you necessarily need to worry about changing repeatedly. But again, they are going to need to confirm that it was something related to the recent planned changes... or not. :-)

When you find something out you can update this question in case it is of use to others. *Especially,* if they tell you that it wasn't a one time thing dealing with a change on their end.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely related to [Changing origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin) in **Same-origin Policy**. As discussed:

> A page may change its own origin with some limitations. A script can set the value of `document.domain` to its current domain or a superdomain of its current domain. If it sets it to a superdomain of its current domain, the shorter domain is used for subsequent origin checks.
>
> For example, assume a script in the document at `http://store.company.com/dir/other.html` executes the following statement:
>   `document.domain = "company.com";`
>
> After that statement executes, the page can pass the origin check with `http://company.com/dir/page.html`

So, as noted:

> When using `document.domain` to allow a subdomain to access its parent securely, you need to set `document.domain` to the same value in both the parent domain and the subdomain. This is necessary even if doing so is simply setting the parent domain back to its original value. Failure to do this may result in permission errors.